# Selecting Names With Specific Subset of Years

Tags: netezza

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    name INT,
    year INT
);


INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (1, 2010);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (1, 2011);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (1, 2012);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (2, 2011);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (2, 2012);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (2, 2013);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (3, 2010);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (3, 2011);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (3, 2012);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (3, 2013);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (4, 2010);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (4, 2010);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (4, 2011);
INSERT INTO my_table (name, year) VALUES (4, 2012);

name year
1 2010
1 2011
1 2012
2 2011
2 2012
2 2013
3 2010
3 2011
3 2012
3 2013
4 2010
4 2010
4 2011
4 2012
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

- I want to only select name's that have rows ONLY in (2010,2011,2012). I only want to select names with years in all 3 of them (i.e. name = 1 and name =4), and ignore everything else.

I thought I could do this with the following code - but this returns name = 1,3,4

```
SELECT name
FROM my_table
WHERE year IN (2010, 2011, 2012)
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 3;
```

To fix this problem, I tried to do this with a roundabout way:

```
WITH ids_in_years AS (
  SELECT name
  FROM my_table
  WHERE year IN (2010, 2011, 2012)
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 3
),
ids_not_in_other_years AS (
  SELECT name
  FROM my_table
  WHERE year NOT IN (2010, 2011, 2012)
)

SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM ids_in_years)
AND name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM ids_not_in_other_years);
```

This returned the correct answer - but it seems quite long.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Idea?:

```
SELECT name
FROM my_table
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN year IN (2010, 2011, 2012) THEN year END) = 3
AND COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 3;
```